# To check a field type is textbox or not

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the below code how to check whether the field is textbox,dropdownlist,checkbox in asp.net.

```
 if (FieldTypeInfo == TextBox)
                {
}

if (FieldTypeInfo == DropDownList)
                {
}


public FieldType FieldTypeInfo { get; set; }




public enum FieldType
    {
        TextBox,
        DropDownList,
        SearchList,
        CheckBox,
        Date
    }
```

Comment: How is your `FieldTypeInfo` declared (defined) in your code? What is its compile-time type?

Comment: it is get set property

Comment: What type has that property? For example with `internal Component FieldTypeInfo { get; set; }` the type would be `Component`.

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen Pls take a look on my update code

Comment: Thanks, it led me to post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `is` keyword in order to check types:

```
if (FieldTypeInfo is TextBox)
{
    var text = ((TextBox)FieldTypeInfo).Text;
    // ...
} 
else if (FieldTypeInfo is DropDownList)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Object.GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx)

```
if(FieldTypeInfo.GetType()== typeOf(TextBox))
{
}
```

Or [is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx)

```
if (FieldTypeInfo is DropDownList)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After your edit where we see you have an enum, the solution is:

```
if (FieldTypeInfo == FieldType.TextBox)
{ 
  ...
}

if (FieldTypeInfo == FieldType.DropDownList)
{
  ...
}
```

However, strongly consider using a `switch` statement, for example:

```
switch (FieldTypeInfo)
{
  case FieldType.TextBox:
    ...
    break;

  case FieldType.DropDownList:
    ...
    break;

  default:
    ...
    break;
}
```

Comment: i did that way but here  if (gmatField.FieldTypeInfo.ToString() == "DropDownList")
                    return gmatField.Dropdownlabel; it always return textbox if it is dropdown or checkbox.

Comment: @user3492682 Why the `.ToString()`? Enum types are made for direct comparisons with `==`.

Comment: @user3492682 Not sure I understand. We do not have enough information to help you. Note, however, that the first member of your `enum` is `TextBox,`. That means that `TextBox` is the default value. If you read a `field` (class-level variable) or auto-property that has never been set, you will get the default value (`TextBox`) of the enum type.

Comment: yes the enum set textbox value has default how to overcome this issue.pls provide me some solution

Comment: @user3492682 Someone needs to write to the property before you read it. Write like `FieldTypeInfo = XXX;` (from an instance method in the same class), or like `someClassInstance.FieldTypeInfo = XXX;` when you write to the property that belongs to instance `someClassInstance`.